# How to remove toolbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I want to hide toolbar when a specific row is selected

This is the code if specific row in pickers is selected, show keyboard and input characters

```
if self.emailPickers[row] == "input by myself" {
            email2Field.text = ""
            email2Field.resignFirstResponder()
            email2Field.inputView = nil
```

[image: I want to remove or hide the toolbar]

Please help me

Comment: try this ```email2Field.inputAccessoryView = nil```

Comment: @JJHA Please close the question once it is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same property for adding and removing the toolbar.

```
email2Field.inputAccessoryView = nil
```